# How to find different value in a column and drop that column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[input data  frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iOPq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yf9y.png)

columns of data frame have different or junk value, how to find and drop that row of column

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list_junk = ["BR55", "BT31", "LZ95", "CT1C", "CT76", "CX39", "CX54"]
```

You want to drop those values?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1":list_junk})
>>> df
   col1
0  BR55
1  BT31
2  LZ95
3  CT1C
4  CT76
5  CX39
6  CX54

>>> df[~df["col1"].isin(list_junk)]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1]
Index: []
```

-EDIT-

You'd have to check first the values of the columns with

```
df.value_counts()
col1
BR55    1
BT31    1
CT1C    1
CT76    1
CX39    1
CX54    1
LZ95    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: no, all are these value, if i get different value like date then how to find n delete

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).